# transformation of SD for a user-defined transformation of a distribution

Tags: logistic, normal-distribution, data-transformation, standard-deviation, monte-carlo

I have a normal distribution of a variable ***y~N(f(x),bc<sup>2x</sup>)***, where ***x*** is the IDV and ***b*** and ***c*** are some estimated parameters. So, the SD of ***y*** is given by ***bc<sup>x</sup>***.

Now I have a transformation of ***y***:

***z=g(y,n)=e<sup>y</sup>(n+1)/(1+e<sup>y</sup>)/n***, where ***n*** is another IDV.

In this case, what is the best way to estimate the SD of ***z***? Or, what is the "?" in ***z~(e<sup>f(x)</sup>(n+1)/(1+e<sup>f(x)</sup>)/n,?)*** ?

I think it would be the fastest if I can have a closed form equation for the SD of ***z*** but I don't know how to do the transformation.

Meanwhile, I can think of the following alternatives:
1. Monte Carlo Simulations, but it is time-consuming, 2. I am wondering if ***0.5[g(f(x)+bc<sup>x</sup>,n)-g(f(x)-bc<sup>x</sup>,n)]*** can be regarded as a reasonable estimator for SD of ***z***

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like $f$, $b$, $c$ and $n$ are irrelevant and potentially distracting.  Ignoring the constant coefficients in $Z$, which affect the variance in simple obvious ways, aren't you just asking what the variance is of the logistic transformation $e^Y/(1+e^Y)=1-1/(1+e^Y)$ of a normal random variable $Y$?  BTW, what is an "IDV" and what assumptions are you making about it?  Is it a number, a random variable, something else?

Comment: I think so... Let's say I already have obtained a set of values for (b,c,x, n and f(x), then how do I transform the SD for y into the SD for z, noting that z = 1-1/(1+e^Y) ?

Comment: It does't transform, because it depends on both the mean and variance of $Y$, but you can compute it numerically to high precision and, for certain prescribed regimes of the mean and variance of $Y$, you can develop approximations in various ways.